# Suggested questions order in "Ask Question"

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

In "Ask Question" page of SE sites displays list of question already asked based on the title of the current question, it would be helpful if the questions are ordered based on the tags if tags are added in the current question being asked.

For example:

In Stackoverflow if the question is "Call super class method" and the tag is [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), first two questions are in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [java](/questions/tagged/java). If those questions are in c# it will be helpful and reduce duplicate questions.

Comment: How are they currently ordered?